# Key storage for cryptography in a web application

Tags: java, spring, security, cryptography

I'm building a web application that has up until now collected and stored data only of low sensitivity, in the next few months the web application will need to begin collecting more sensitive data and so I have determined that I need to ensure that the data is encrypted when stored in the database so that it cannot be accessed even if the database is compromised.

I have read the [OWASP Cryptographic Cheat Sheet](https://github.com/OWASP/CheatSheetSeries/blob/master/cheatsheets/Cryptographic_Storage_Cheat_Sheet.md), most of which makes a lot of sense, however there is one point I can't get my head around.

> Rule - Store unencrypted keys away from the encrypted data If the keys
>   are stored with the data then any compromise of the data will easily
>   compromise the keys as well. Unencrypted keys should never reside on
>   the same machine or cluster as the data.

**Possible solutions:**

1. Store the key un-encrypted as `root`, load the key into the application which runs as a less privileged user at startup via an environment variable, so the key is only ever stored as the root user. --- This doesn't satisfy the OWASP rule as the key is still located on the server.
2. Encrypt the key on the filesystem, and require a second key, such as a password to decrypt that at startup that is entered by a human user. --- While this satisfies the OWASP rule, its impractical to require a human user to be on hand as the application starts up.

---

Is there a recommended or recognised solution to this problem?

While the problem is technology agnostic, technology specific solutions are welcome, i'm presently using:

- Java
- Spring
- Hibernate
- MySQL
- Centos

Comment: Aren´t you already storing the unencrypted key (on the server) away from the unencrypted data (in the database) as long as they are on different machines?

Comment: @Glains well yes thats correct I suppose, but i'm thinking if someone had managed to get privileges to access the encryption key there would be little stopping them from also obtaining db access credentials too which means they have everything they need to get access to the sensitive data. Is requiring root access to the key on the web server enough is the question?

Comment: amazon has their [KMS](https://aws.amazon.com/kms/) service that purports to help with this sort of thing.  that said, I don't to see how their service actually helps e.g. once an attacker is into your web server they presumably can get AWS API keys pretty easily (ephemeral or not) and hence decrypt whatever they want.  presumably things will be logged, but not sure what else it can do.  maybe somebody else can point out where I'm wrong